# iPhone 3rd Party Controls?

Tags: iphone

I was wondering if there are any 3rd party controls for use with the iPhone that are available, even better if usable from Interface Builder. From what I can gather, the answer is no.

I come from a Microsoft .NET background where of course there are tons of controls available from 3rd parties. I'm curious if this is a general Mac development ecosystem fact, i.e. no 3rd party controls for sale, or just an iPhone one, or if I've just missed finding them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its a case of requirement. The iPhone has all of the controls you'd need for an average app.

I think those that have written 3rd party controls would rather keep them for themselves, since that's what sets their app out from the rest (which is an important thing to do on the App Store).

Subclassing `UIControl` and writing your own isn't a difficult thing to do. I did it with my rating control that I released on Github recently: http://github.com/jasarien/JSFavStarControl

There is also the [Three20 project](http://three20.info), which contains a lot of UI classes (not so much in the way of individual controls though).

Answer (score 1):

Also, there are others offering custom controls for sale. Most of them could be replicated with a small amount of effort; however, some people just prefer the easiest possible route. For an example, check out: [Dr. Touch's Part Store](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/parts-store/).

//Note: I am in no way affiliated with "Dr. Touch" and am not endorsing him or his pricing.